# Templates from templatecache not rendering bindings when data is returned from $http in 1.2+

Tags: angularjs, http, templates, caching

I have a basic app, that fetches some data through the $http service, however it doesnt render the data correct in the template, when the template is served from the template cache. My code looks like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

api service:

```
.factory('api', function($http, $q) {

    return {
        getCars: function() {
            return $http.get('api/cars');
        }
    };
})
```

the controller using the service:

```
.controller('carsCtrl', function($scope, api) {

    api.getCars().success(function(data) {
        $scope.cars = data;
    });

})
```

the route setup:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/cars', {
         templateUrl: 'cars.html',
         controller: 'carsCtrl'
    });
});
```

and the template `cars.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
     {{ car }}
</div>
```

this works the first time the browser hits `/cars`, however, if I push the back on forward button in the browser to hit the url a second time without a page reload, the `{{car}}` is not being rendered. If the `cars.html` is put in the templateCache like this:

```
angular.module('app').run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('cars.html', '<div ng-repeat="car in cars">{{ car }}</div>');
});
```

the `{{car}}` binding is not rendered either.

I suspect this has something to do with Angular not unwrapping promises in templates anymore, but not totally sure. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to write this code correctly?

Comment: As an observation, `$http` returns a promise, so you can shorten the `getCars()` function to simply `return $http.get('api/cars')`

Comment: Yeah you are right, I have updated my question with the changes. They did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I saw some syntax errors in your code (maybe you didn't copy the code but typed it manually for SO not sure). Also you returned deferred instead of deferred.promise. What you trying to achieve works just fine:

[Plnkr Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/7CQemyD5YVFSq5h22tqt/preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will make some corrections to the post, I did type it in directly :) Wonder why thats not the behaviour I get locally... Im not sure if the navigation back and forth that is causing the trouble can be replicated in a plnkr?

Comment: Well, you can get back and forward. It still works fine for me in plnkr.